# how react-native renders the TouchableOpacity components on the same row - horizontally

Tags: react-native, reactjs, horizontallist, touchableopacity

I have a product component - TouchableOpacity as shown in picture. Number of products is dynamic.Thing is that, I want to post 2 products on each row. 
But I can't. It renders them vertically, although I set horizontal as true.
How can I solve, it? Do you have any suggestion?

[image]

Here is my styling of the component

[image]

And it is how they are rendered
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for `flexDirection` in react-native is `column`. You should set it to `row` in the style of the container of your list of `TouchableOpacity`.

Here is an example from the official documentation : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flex-direction

If you want your elements, that exceed the container size to be wrapped to the next line, you can set `flexWrap:"wrap"`. 
Here is the doc: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexwrap

Comment: Thank you. When I set flexDirection to 'row' in styling of TouchableOpacity it renders only 2 products on the first row. Products after second one is not shown.@Kevin Amiranoff

Comment: I guess that comes from component not being wrapped to the next `row`. Does it work if you set `flexWrap: "noWrap"` to the container of `TouchableOpacity` . For example the `View` above your list of `TouchableOpacity`. And the doc : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexwrap

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day :) I tried nowrap but it did not work. However, when I set 'wrap' instead of 'unwrap' just for try, it somehow worked.

Comment: :) Of course it is `"wrap"` that wraps elements... I am an idiot lol. Good job ! I'll edit my answer.